# Bad argument #3 (CFrame expected, got Object)

Tags: lua, roblox

I've been working on a game on Roblox and right now Im trying to make it so that the character's Torso or HumanoidRootPart is welded to the spawn part that ive placed on the map.

```
character:FindFirstChild("Torso").CFrame = asp[1].CFrame
```

I keep getting this error though:

> **Bad argument #3 (CFrame expected, got Object)**

Does anyone have any idea what it means and how to fix it? I've looked through all the forums I could find and none of it helped.

Comment: This is not the line which generates the error.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Actually it could be if asp[1] is an object with a child named "CFrame" which would leave this code referencing the child instead of the property

Comment: @Taazar - So, what is the function which 3-rd argument is mentioned in the error message?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Whoops, forgot to notice that part

Answer (score 0):

The first value of the array asp don't store an array. It should be like this :

```
local array = {key = CFrame3.new(0,5,0)}
```